# send nested json object

Tags: javascript, json

i have a  simple json post request.
i have nested json object to send ,
the key "text" contains 2 subkeys  like this :
"text" : {"nom":"user1","browser":"chrome"}

the 2 subkeys ( "name","browser") there values are javascript params, i want to replace them in the json object to send . i tried this!

```
var var1=session.get("userConnected");
var var2=checkBrowser();
var values =
{ type: "text"
, text:"{\"name\":\"+var1+\",\"browser\":" +var2+"}" 
};
```

Please how do i replace javascript params inside json object?  and thanks alot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Use `JSON.stringify` it will make life a lot easier.

```js
var var1 = "John Doe"; // session.get("userConnected");
var var2 = "chrome"; //checkBrowser();
var values = {
  type: "text",
  text: JSON.stringify({
    name: var1,
    browser: var2
  })
};
console.log(values);
console.log(JSON.parse(values.text));
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes.  *Decode* the JSON object into an in-memory structure, change that structure, then *Encode* the resulting structure as JSON.  Don't try to fiddle with the file as a string.